# Android enter SplashActivity when app process is killed instead of MainActivity

Tags: android, kotlin

In my app all important data and API calls are done in SplashActivity. After that app enters MainAcitivity. Works well but we have one problematic case.
When I enter the app to the mainActivity and than put app to the background, after some time, the app process gets killed (logical behaviour because of memory management, all fine). But problem is when we enter the app again from the task collection, my app goes directly to the mainActivity. Since the data is deleted, My activity is blank.

I guess we could solve this by for example detecting in my MainActivity when it starts is my data empty and than if it is use intent to go to splash again. But I really don't like this solution. Is looks to me as a "butcher solution", not classy and nice in code and it also makes app start slower than in the situation if app starts totally fresh.

I would like to know is there any way that in situation where app process is killed we can start app fresh (immediately from SplashActivity instead of going back and forth from main to splash and using additional logic).

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could start that work in your Application class instead of an Activity. Official guidance is to have only one activity and use Fragments to represent different screens.

Comment: You shouldn't be using a SplashActivity in the first place. Have you considered [migrating to the actual Splash Screen API](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen/migrate)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake this is app old 5 years and we are making redesing and reskining. We didn't change the old way of doing the heavylifting in the splashActivity. It would be too much time consuming since the app goes on the production in around 20 days

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yes still the butcher style solution, but I like it more cause we don't lose time and resources going to mainActivity and back. Regarding only 1 activity I don't agree with this for all cases. I can think of very complex apps where using only 1 activity would be bad in my opinion.

Comment: Your app is going to look broken to every user on Android 12+ if you don't migrate to the Splash Screen APIs - that's about 50% of your users. It isn't an optional migration you can ignore.

Comment: @ianhanniballake we have huge amount of logic inside SplashActivity. Where to transfer all of this, it is not a 2 hour thing. Also problem happens only in cases where user left app for 3+ hours in background and uses other apps and device runs out of memory? It is not very often. Even than with a mentioned workaround I can return back to Splash again and start all over.

Comment: @Tenfour04 how do you mean to accomplish checking in Application class? If the emptynes of the data that I need to check in MainActivity to trigger going back to Splash is collected in SplashActivity, than in my application class, this data will always be empty, right? I have no logic to use here to determine do I need to go back to Splash or not. I googled about trying to detect if process death happened, but it looks that those ways are not super convenient to use and can not tell in 100% situations if process death happened